# How can I determine if Apache is installed on a system?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint on my computer but I don't know how to find out whether Apache2 is on it or where it is actually installed. I run my web browser (PHP installed) with `http://localhost` as a URL and it works.

Comment: what do you mean by PHP installed?

Comment: How is that related to c, c# or unix?

Comment: you want to know the path where are the files from that site?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would recommend

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
```

It lists all installed packages that contain "apache" in their name. For example:

```
apache2                                         install
apache2-doc                                     install
apache2-mpm-prefork                             install
apache2-utils                                   install
apache2.2-bin                                   install
apache2.2-common                                install
libapache2-mod-php5                             install
libapache2-svn                                  install
```

It indicates that the package `apache2` is installed on the system.

Another approach, to find *any* running HTTP daemon on the default port would be:

```
sudo lsof -nPi | grep ":80 (LISTEN)"
```

Which lists something like:

```
apache2    1026     root    4u  IPv6    3739      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    3966 www-data    4u  IPv6    3739      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4014 www-data    4u  IPv6    3739      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4015 www-data    4u  IPv6    3739      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4016 www-data    4u  IPv6    3739      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: ``-bash: dpkg: command not found`` is the above done in a certain directory?

Comment: @elliotrock No, try running it with `sudo`.

Comment: `-bash: dpkg: command not found` same error on aws linux even tried with sudo.

Comment: This question is about Linux Mint. Using dpkg on platforms that don't have it is pointless.

Answer (score 16):

Try the [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command:

```
# which apache2
```

In my experience, the Apache binary is located in `/usr/sbin` on most installations.

Comment: Depending on distro you might also try which with 'apache' and 'httpd'

Answer (score 7):

To check whether if apache is running or not (the status), type:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

at the command line.

Comment: This only works where Apache is installed as a (`sysv` etc) service; which admittedly will cover a lot of cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a `which httpd` as user root.

Comment: Afraid to say, but on Mint (a Debian derivative) it would be `apache` or `apache2`, but not `httpd` ...

Answer (score 3):

As I recall, Mint is based on Ubuntu, so you should be able to check `apt-cache policy apache2`:

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.20-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main amd64 Packages
```

In this case, you can see it's not installed on my system. If you haven't asked for it to be installed, it's probably not -- I doubt it's part of the default distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bash command:

```
if [[ -z $(apache2 -v 2>/dev/null) ]] && [[ -z $(httpd -v 2>/dev/null) ]]; then echo "Apache not found"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As root, you can test if apache is running under process name httpd, apache, or apache2, using

```
ps -A | grep 'apache\|httpd'
```

But again, this will only find apache if the process is running.

Comment: If works even if you are not root.

Comment: Ah cool, wasn't sure if non-privileged users could list global processes, thanks.